# Notation about probability

Tags: probability, notation

After reading several books, the notations in probability are not very clear in my mind.
Take a random variable $X$ following a law $\mu$. Usually, one writes this by $X\sim\mu$. Now, take a function $F$ which depends on $X$ and one wishes to write the probability of $F$ exceeding a defined threshold $a$. Should I write:

$\mathbb{P}_{X\sim\mu}[F(X)\geq a$]

or

$\mu_{X\sim\mu}[F(X)\geq a$]

To me it should be the second one but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: Why not just $\mathbb{P}[F(X)\geq a$]  where $X \sim \mu$ ?

Comment: Why not, but then what does the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ correspond to?